# how can i compound postUid and Userid

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I create one screen which has posts from users.
The main problem is, current user always see the all posts, BUT also the current user always see name of yourself on the card.

For example app has 3 posts from 3 different user, but when i logged in the app, i see JUST MY NAME on the card, but only 1 post is mine, the others not mine.

I add some photos and codes in bottom:

```
class HomePageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collectionGroup('Posts').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshotMsg) {
        if (!snapshotMsg.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshotMsg.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (!snapshotMsg.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                final dataMsg = snapshotMsg.data.documents[index];
                return FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshotUser) {
                    if (!snapshotMsg.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else {
                      final dataUser = snapshotUser.data;
                      return Card(...)
```

here, if i want to show username etc. i used this code also:

```
Text(dataUser['username']),
```

Photos from problem:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem with this code:

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(dataMsg.reference.parent.parent.id).get(),

That's it.
Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work. You can mark your own answer as accepted also.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the current user userid to get the user snapshot. You will need to look up the user corresponding to the author id on the card, in this case the dataMessage, to get the comment author's username

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Look at rhe user id you are using in the future builder that gets the user for the card. It is the current userid, so you will get your current users username on each card. Does it work if you make that userid in the futurebuilder equal to the userid on the card?

Comment: i do not know how to write userid (no current uid, i know this), but it works if it is like this:

`FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get(),`

Comment: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(dataMsg.reference.parent.parent.id).get(),` -- you need to load the _parent_ User record for the Post.  Pro Tip: You probably want to cache the User lookups to avoid a lot of redundant I/O.